# how to send array values to html pages in express js

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, express

i have this simple app.js using express JS\NODEJS

```
var express= require("express");
var path= require("path");
var app= express();    
app.use(express.static(__dirname));
var users=[ {   userName: "faizan",  password: "faizan",  email: "mfkj@live.com"},
            {   userName: "ali",     password: "ali",     email: "xyz@live.com"},
            {   userName: "hussain", password: "hussain", email: "abc@live.com"},
            {   userName: "hassan",  password: "hassan",  email: "xyz@mail.com"},
];

app.get('/',function(request , response){
    response.sendFile(__dirname+ '/index.html');

});

app.get('/frmSignUp', function(request, response){
    users.push({
        userName: request.query["userName"],
        password: request.query["password"],
        email: request.query["email"]
    });
    response.sendFile(__dirname+ '/dashboard.html');
    //how can i show my user array items in my dashboard html page?? Question1

});

app.get('/frmSignIn',function(request, response)
{
    if(users.contains(request.query["userName"])) //this is invalid
// is there any way available to check userName in array that is this exists?
    response.sendFile(__dirname+ '/dashboard.html');

})

var server =app.listen(3010, function(){
    console.log("server running on port "+ server.address().port);
})
```

i have **index SignUp SignIn and Dashboard HTML pages** in root directory. i have question which are commented in above code please let me know is these thing possible for me to do??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To answer your questions:

1. Use templates. Probably the easiest way to do this coming from existing html is to use [`ejs`](https://github.com/visionmedia/ejs/) (`npm install ejs` first in your project root directory). Example:

   - `app.js`:

     ```
     app.set('view engine', 'ejs');

     // ...

     app.get('/frmSignUp', function(request, response) {
       users.push({
         userName: request.query["userName"],
         password: request.query["password"],
         email: request.query["email"]
       });
       response.render('dashboard.ejs', { users: users });
     });
     ```
   - `dashboard.ejs`:

     ```
     <html>
       <head>
         <title>Dashboard</title>
       </head>
       <body>
         <h1>Users</h1>
         <ul>
         <% users.forEach(function(user) { %>
           <li><%= user.userName %></li>
         <% }); %>
         </ul>
       </body>
     </html>
     ```
2. Since you have an array of objects and you're checking against a `userName` string, you'd need to manually loop over the `users` array and compare `userName`s.

Comment: can you define first part of answer more!

Comment: thank you very much but one modification require is that make a folder in root (named views) and place dashboard.js there

Comment: You can [change the views path](http://expressjs.com/4x/api.html#app-settings) if you want something different. The relevant app setting is `views`.